# Type traits style to test if T is a basic_string<> or printable string-like type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, type-traits

Im writing a [template](/questions/tagged/template) that can print ranges using ostream's :

```
template<class T>
struct range_out {  
  range_out(T& range) : r_(range) {
  }
  T& r_;

  //static_assert(std::is_same<T::); //check that T is not std::string (std::string, etc. should just use << operator directly instead)
};

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, range_out<T>& range) {
  constexpr std::string_view sep{ std::is_arithmetic<T>::value ? ", " : "', '" }; //<<-- better way to check for string-like type ?

  if (!range.r_.empty()) {
    out << '[';
    for (auto& e : range.r_) {
      out << e << sep;
    }
    out << std::string(sep.size(), '\b') << "]";
  }
  return out;
}
```

Is there some 'easy' way to check that T is of a basic_string<> type ? (I do have [boost](/questions/tagged/boost) if that will help)

My second minor issue is that i would like to put in qoutes around 'string-like' types, but again, is there some 'easy' way to test this im overlooking ?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "T is of a basic_string<> type"? In a comment you said you want to include `char const*`, which doesn't to me sound like "a basic_string<> type".

Comment: The `basic_string<Ch>` seems misplaced, because in all other types you use `Ch=char` . Or are you unaware that `std::string` is really `std::basic_string<char>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just using this one line trait:

```
template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_string_type_v = std::is_convertible_v<T, std::string_view>;
```

It works fine for several 'string-like' types:

```
static_assert(is_string_type_v<std::string>);
static_assert(is_string_type_v<std::string_view>);
static_assert(is_string_type_v<const char*>);
static_assert(is_string_type_v<char*>);
static_assert(is_string_type_v<char* const>);
static_assert(is_string_type_v<const char* const>);
static_assert(is_string_type_v<char (&)[5]>);
static_assert(is_string_type_v<const char (&)[5]>);
```

I steal this trait from [`std::string`'s c++17 constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string), since the type which can implicitly converts to a `std::string_view` can be considered as a 'string-like' type.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a custom trait:

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template
<
    typename x_MaybeString
> struct
is_basic_string: public ::std::false_type {};

template
<
    typename x_Char
,   typename x_Traits
,   typename x_Allocator
> struct
is_basic_string<::std::basic_string<x_Char, x_Traits, x_Allocator>>: public ::std::true_type {};
```

I guess you can write similar traits for 'string-like' types. `std::string_view` is probably a good candidate.

Comment: Brilliant - with "string-like" i also include `const char*` for example - but im guessing that easy enough (just use a template to strip `cv-stuff` ?)

Comment: @darune yeah, something like that